# VueJS / TypeScript: get json data from html

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

just wondering what is best practice for using *VueJS* without a "real" JSON API.

I have a json string to read in my application, but only available in the HTML source.

Tried the following:

```
<div id="app">
        <application :apidata="initRawData(myRenderedJsonString)"></application>
</div>
```

**myRenderedJsonString** comes from a CMS output and is already valid JSON.

What is the best way to handle and give child components access to given string?

Thanks

Mikel

Comment: Render the data inside a script as a javascript variable and make it available when you create your Vue.

Comment: Do you need to write it back somewhere or are you just using as input?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 
I prefer NOT to define a global JS var inline to avoid the data being accessible from everywhere. 
Yes, I need this data bindable / reactive.
Currently, I solved it with a data attribute on the root node (data-init="myjsonstring"). In my Vue app, I read this data attribute in the beforeMount observer and assign the given string to a variable in the data scope. 
beforeMount: function () {
  // console.log(this.$el);
  let json: any = this.$el.dataset.init;
  this.json = json;
 },